# When I open an app then it closed and logcat error is return a null pointer. How to solve this error?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
at rishabh.example.chatapp.ChatsFragment.onCreateView(ChatsFragment.java:51)

Code of ChatsFragment.java

```
public class ChatsFragment extends Fragment
{
    private View PrivateChatsView;
    private RecyclerView chatsList;

    private DatabaseReference ChatsRef, UsersRef;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private String currentUserID;

    public ChatsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        PrivateChatsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chats, container, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        chatsList = (RecyclerView) PrivateChatsView.findViewById(R.id.chats_list);
        chatsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        return PrivateChatsView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
                .setQuery(ChatsRef, Contacts.class)
                .build();


        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder> adapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Contacts, ChatsViewHolder>(options) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Contacts model)
                    {
                        final String usersIDs = getRef(position).getKey();
                        final String[] retImage = {"default image"};

                        UsersRef.child(usersIDs).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                                {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("image"))
                                    {
                                        retImage[0] = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                                        Picasso.get().load(retImage[0]).into(holder.profileImage);
                                    }

                                    final String retName = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                                    final String retStatus = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();

                                    holder.userName.setText(retName);
                                    holder.userStatus.setText("Last Seen: " + "\n" + "Date " + " Time");


                                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View view)
                                        {
                                            Intent chatIntent = new Intent(getContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_id", usersIDs);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_name", retName);
                                            chatIntent.putExtra("visit_user_image", retImage[0]);
                                            startActivity(chatIntent);
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
                            {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public ChatsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
                    {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_display_layout, viewGroup, false);
                        return new ChatsViewHolder(view);
                    }
                };

        chatsList.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    public static class ChatsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        CircleImageView profileImage;
        TextView userStatus, userName;

        public ChatsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            profileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.users_profile_image);
            userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_name);
            userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_status);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where the code is giving error and could not able to find the bug. Please help me to find the bug.

Error pointing on the line:  currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

This line is used in many activities and not given any error but on this activity this line is giving a null error. Please help me so that I can solve this error.

Comment: "and not given any error", yes, it is "giving" an error. Basically, it is throwin a NullPointerException. Figure out which field isn't instantiated, then instantiate it before using it.

Comment: `mAuth.getCurrentUser()` is `null`. Find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the current user isn't initialized when your `ChatsFragment` is created.

1. The simplest fix is to not create the `ChatsFragment` until the user is initialized.
2. Another simple fix is to only attach the database listener if there is a current user:

   ```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    }
   ```
3. A common alternative is to wait until the user is initialized inside the `ChatsFragment` before attaching a listener to the database. You do that with a so-called auth state listener:

   ```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuth.onAuthStateChanged(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Contacts").child(currentUserID);
                UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
            }
        }
    };
   ```